# My cssed Button that it's supposed to show up a list has function of sumbit

Tags: php, css, button, menu, dropdown

So i got a button that it's supposed when you click on it shows up a list to choice . But When i click on it , it attempts to sumbit the values in the text input .

Css

```
 .dropbtn {
background-color: #3498DB;
color: white;
padding: 16px;
font-size: 16px;
border: none;
cursor: pointer; 
}
.dropbtn:hover, .dropbtn:focus {
background-color: #2980B9;
}
.dropdown {
position: relative;
display: inline-block;
}
.dropdown-content {
display: none;
position: absolute;
background-color: #f1f1f1;
min-width: 160px;
overflow: auto;
box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
color: black;
padding: 12px 16px;
text-decoration: none;
display: block;
}

.dropdown a:hover {background-color: #ddd;}

.show {display: block;}
```

the drop down button

```
   <div class="dropdown">
    <button onclick="myFunction()" class="dropbtn">Dropdown</button>
<div id="ccmonth" class="dropdown-content">
<a href="#January">January</a>
<a href="#February">February</a>
<a href="#March">March </a>
<a href="#April">April</a>
<a href="#May">May</a>
<a href="#June">June</a>
<a href="#July">July</a>
<a href="#August">August</a>
<a href="#September">September</a>
<a href="#October">October</a>
<a href="#November">November</a>
<a href="#December">December</a>
```

Functions

```
 function myFunction() {
document.getElementById("ccmonth").classList.toggle("show");
 }

 window.onclick = function(event) {
   if (!event.target.matches('.dropbtn')) {

var dropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-content");
var i;
for (i = 0; i < dropdowns.length; i++) {
  var openDropdown = dropdowns[i];
  if (openDropdown.classList.contains('show')) {
    openDropdown.classList.remove('show');
```

I really need this fixed , cause it's the half of my next project any help please

Comment: What's the meaning of "When i click on it , it attempts to sumbit the values in the text input . Css". Do you receive $_GET variables or what?

Comment: When i click on it , it does this https://ibb.co/dPQX9d

Comment: please provide complete JS. It's incomplete.

Comment: Actually that's the full JS :p

Answer (score 1):

I think that your problem is that the button is inside a form so when you click it it tries to do the submit. You can maintain what you have but in the onclick event you have to say the form to not be submitted.
It would be something like this:

```
window.onclick = function(event) {
   event.preventDefault();
   if (!event.target.matches('.dropbtn')) {

var dropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-content");
var i;
for (i = 0; i < dropdowns.length; i++) {
  var openDropdown = dropdowns[i];
  if (openDropdown.classList.contains('show')) {
    openDropdown.classList.remove('show');
```